# Is multiplying and dividing inequalities valid?

Tags: inequality

I am facing certain problems in solving inequalities. I do not know whether multiplying and dividing inequalities works or not but it has helped me solve many problems. Here are some problems which cannot be solved using multiplying and dividing. Why does the rule not apply here?

> $1$. If $a$,$b$, $c$ are positive real numbers then prove that $$(a+1)^7 (b+1)^7 (c+1)^7 > 7^7 a^4b^4c^4$$

My approach:

Applying AM-GM to $a$ and $1$ we get $(a+1) > 2\sqrt{a}$ or $(a+1)^7 > 2^7 a^\frac{7}{2}$. Proceeding similarly, we get $$(a+1)^7 (b+1)^7 (c+1)^7 > 2^{21} (abc)^\frac{7}{2}$$

Actual answer:

Apply AM-GM to $a$,$b$,$c$,$ab$,$bc$,$ca$,$abc$

> $2$. If $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers such that $x+y = 8$, then find the minimum value of $$\left(1+ \frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)$$.

My approach:

Applying AM-GM to $1$ , $\frac{1}{x}$ and $1$ , $\frac{1}{y}$ and multiplying the inequalities we get $$\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{y}\right) ≥ 4 \sqrt{\frac{1}{xy}}$$ Substituting $y = 8 - x$ and solving the quadratic we get $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{x(8-x)}} ≥ \frac{1}{4}$$   or the minimum value of the required expression is $1$

Actual Answer: $25/16$

Comment: You've just proved different inequalities than the ones asked for.  In the second instance, you say that the minimum value is $1$, but you haven't proved that.  You've just proved that the product is $\geq 1$ when in fact, it obvious from the beginning that the product is strictly greater than $1$.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want the answer. I have already mentioned it in my question. I want to know why multiplying inequalities does not work.

So see it is not necessary that all the question can be solved by only 1 method. If all the question were to get solved by 1 method then what is the fun in doing maths? Take for example let say you have just completed triangles portion. You are assigned 10 problems out of which top 9 you were able to do with similarity but 10th was of Heron's formula. That is why instead of relying on one method you should try to use more and more methods. Also if you want help in first part [here it is](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/if-abc-are-positive-real-numbers-then-prove-that-left-left-1a-right-left/). You can try second on your own and if you fail I will definitely help you

Comment: Okay I got it. I initially thought that the Right Hand side of the inequality is a fingerprint of the left hand side. Later I realised that there can exist many expressions in the right hand side for a given expression in the left hand side. I have to start the proof not only by considering the left hand side but also the right hand side. Also I have to check whether the equality really holds or not ... Am I correct?

Comment: @SDas yes you can definitely try this

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM $$(a+1)^7(b+1)^7(c+1)^7=\prod_{cyc}\left(4\cdot\frac{a}{4}+3\cdot\frac{1}{3}\right)^7\geq$$
$$\geq\left(7^7\right)^3\prod_{cyc}\left(\left(\frac{a}{4}\right)^4\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3\right)=\frac{7^{21}}{4^{12}3^9}a^4b^4c^4>7^7a^4b^4c^4.$$
The last inequality we can prove by the following way.
$$\frac{7^{21}}{4^{12}3^9}=7^7\cdot\frac{7^{14}}{2^{24}3^9}=7^7\cdot\frac{7^6\cdot7^8}{2^{24}3^9}>7^7\cdot\frac{(2^4\cdot3^8)\cdot\left(2^{11}\right)^2}{2^{24}3^9}=7^7\cdot\frac{4}{3}>7^7.$$
Now, we see why your work does not help:

we need to get $\sqrt[7]{a^4b^4c^4}$, which I got, but you got $\sqrt{a^7b^7c^7},$ which is bad.

The second inequality.

In your way you did not save the case of the equality occurring: $x=y=4$.

By your way we need $1=\frac{1}{x}$ and $1=\frac{1}{y},$ which is impossible for $x+y=8.$

Now, we can get a solution.

For $x=y=4$ we obtain a value $\frac{25}{16}.$

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that:
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)\geq\frac{25}{16}$$ or $$1+8+xy\geq\frac{25}{16}xy$$ or
$$xy\leq16,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$xy\leq\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2=16.$$

Comment: I do not want the answer. I have already mentioned it in my question. I want to know why multiplying inequalities does not work.

Comment: @S Das  I added something. See now. Also, In my solution for the first inequality  we got a best estimation.